# Are "aquarium" and "fish" tags redundant?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Are the [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) and [fish](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish) tags redundant, or do they have different purposes?

You can have an aquarium with something other than fish in it (frogs, turtles, shellfish, etc.)  However, the majority of aquarium posts will be about fish, and all fish posts will be about aquariums.

Comment: Aquariums also house lizards and crabs, so they're not strictly fully aquatic or even at all aquatic...

Comment: @JohnCavan I think that an aquarium used to house a non-aquatic pet like a snake or a lizard is called a terrarium in that case, but I see your point.

Answer (score 12):

Keep [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) and [fish](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish) as separate tags.

The consequence of this is that likely the vast majority of fish questions will have both tags.  However, there will be some questions with the [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) tag paired with another animal tag (such as [frogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frogs) or [turtles](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turtles)), and there could even be questions with only the [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) tag and no animal tag (for example, a question about aquarium maintenance or repair).

Comment: … and [tag:fish] living in a [tag:pond] are on topic as well.

Comment: Most of those pond questions are from a former user; I could only imagine her response to this question.  It would have been the ultimate rebuttal.

Answer (score 6):

Most people I know here in semi-temperate Oregon have had pond fish, which are often as much pets as the aquarium fish. I would think that aquarium or pond tags would be related to the environment and fish or frogs or turtles the animals involved.

Examples:
"What is the best way to keep my aquarium at a constant temperature?" - tag aquarium, don't tag fish
"My aquarium ranges in temperature from X degree to Y degree over the course of a day is that safe for my BREED Z fish?" - tag aquarium and fish
"How do I train my fish to swim through a hoop?" - tag fish and not aquarium, pond, ...
"What is the best pond liner to use?" - tag pond and not fish
"Is pond liner brand X safe for turtles?" - tag pond and turtle

Answer (score -4):

Because the vast majority of aquarium posts will be about fish, it seems like a lot of work to require that all of these questions be tagged with two tags.  The tag [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) could be used for these fish posts, and [fish](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish) could be made a synonym for [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium).  For questions on frogs or turtles that are kept in aquariums, those questions could be tagged both with [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) as well as the animal tag (i.e. [frogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frogs).

Comment: Making an exception for fish seems odd to me - I don't see a problem with more than one tag.

Comment: We've already got [a fish question](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/135/how-much-to-feed-outdoor-goldfish-that-feed-on-insects) that is not really about aquariums.